# SSRS Charts Legend Series 1

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, reporting, ssrs-2012

I am stuck with one of the most irritating problem of SSRS. In my chart, I am displaying all months for months with data and without data. Reason being User wants to see all the months.

now where there is no data in any month then in the legend, SSRS is by default putting Series 1(dont know why called it Series 1)

Instead it should display "Declined", "Re-Directed", "Upheld" but what I am getting is

"Series 1", "Declined", "Re-Directed", "Upheld"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqh9U.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t3WK.jpg

My problem is, User wants to see months with no data but she is not ready to see Series 1 in the legend and I have tried everything but couldn't figure out the solution.

Please help:

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: I have saved a link of the image and it is for "DEC 2014" where there is no data so in the legend, it is coming up as a Series 1 with blue block.

Comment: In another image, there are quite a few blank months so it will give you a clear picture of my issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I have updated my Stored Procedure. I wrote a Case Statement in Stored Procedure stating that where it's blank in the chart then show it as a 'No Data Yet' in the Legend.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ckTh.jpg

Image might explain better :)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old but I found another way to hide Series1 on the chart.

1. Click on a Series
2. Go to the Properties pane, Appearance > (Hidden) option.
3. Click on the Expression button (looks like Fx)
4. Enter in the following:

`=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!GROUPING_OPTION.Value)=TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)`

Please see this image for an example:
[ScreenshotOfMyReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcHKt.png)

Sorry- I don't have enough reputation to embed the image yet.